# Generar un retorno diferente según condiciones desde controlador de laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

Soy nuevo en Laravel, alguien me podría ayudar, quisiera que un controlador, en este caso el método update, al momento de intentar actualizar me haga una consulta previa y si esa consulta me valida que si puedo actualizar lo haga, de lo contrario no, en el caso de que sea NO me retorne algo como un error para mostrar.

Lo que sucede es que ya tengo la consulta previa pero lo que no sé es que si la consulta me indica que no debo actualizar lo tome como error o como un mensaje diferente. Es que siempre se lleva a cabo correctamente la ejecución del controlador.

```
if ($aux->formatos_id == "2" && $request->get('formatos_id') == "1") {
            File::delete($aux->archivo);
            $array['archivo'] = NULL;
        } else if ($aux->formatos_id == "1" && $request->get('formatos_id') == "2") {
            $validar_ejemplares = DB::table('ejemplares')->where('recursos_id', $recurso->id)->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*)'))->groupBy('recursos_id')->get();
        }
```

Necesito que si voy a actualizar de ID 2 a 1 se pueda, si es 1 a 2 NO se pueda pero que no se siga ejecutando el metodo del controlador.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para finalizar una función de un controlador en Laravel siempre tienes que finalizar con return.

Algunos ejemplos:

```
return view('Nombre del archivo de la vista');
//Retorna a una vista.
return response()->json($user);
//Retorna la colección $user como en formato json
```